# IndexError: string index out of range in for loop

Tags: python

I am so baffled at why this will not work please can someone explain.
This is the variable declaration

```
word = random.choice(WORDS)

tries = '-'*len(word)
```

this is where the error message is pointing to:

```
if guess in word:
        
        new = ''
        print(len(word),len(tries))
        
        for i in range(len(tries)):
            
            if word[i] == guess:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += tries[i]
                
            tries = new
```

I get this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "S:\programming\python\chapter5\hangMan.py", line 54, in 
new += tries[i]
IndexError: string index out of range

I don't have a clue how the index could be put of range the i counter shouldn't ever be out of range. I have investigated and it always stops on the second iteration. Please help this is really frustrating lol.

Comment: You are redefining `tries = new` inside the loop. That probably belongs outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the tries value to new every time the for loop runs. it should be unindented by one block because then it will run after the loop finished.
instead of

```
for i in range(len(tries)):
            
    if word[i] == guess:
        new += guess
    else:
       new += tries[i]
                
    tries = new
```

do this

```
for i in range(len(tries)):
            
    if word[i] == guess:
        new += guess
    else:
       new += tries[i]
                
tries = new
```

Comment: Yh I just realized lol. Thank you for your time though :)